# Unable to sign in kubernetes dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes-dashboard

[image]After follow all steps to create service account and role binding unable to sign in

```
kubectl create serviceaccount dashboard -n default

kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n default --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:dashboard
```

and apply yml file

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system

--------
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

Getting following error when i click on sign in for config sevice

```
[![{
 "status": 401,
 "plugins": \[\],
 "errors": \[
  {
   "ErrStatus": {
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "MSG_LOGIN_UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR",
    "reason": "Unauthorized",
    "code": 401
   }
  }][1]][1]
```

Comment: What steps are you following?

Comment: kubectl create serviceaccount dashboard -n default
kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n default --clusterrole=cluster-admin   --serviceaccount=default:dashboard

Comment: I have update the question please check

Comment: how do you get token?

Comment: kubectl -n kube-system describe secret admin-user-token-hwl6g

Comment: you should use `kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')`. It can print a few tokens, you need to find yours. Try all with type `kubernetes.io/service-account-token`

Comment: I have use that already.

Comment: How we can know it if you didn't describe it in the question? Did you try all tokens? How many tokens were printed?

Comment: Name:         admin-user-token-hwl6g
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name: admin-user
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 74436e0d-e34d-46a9-aae8-6ee90cf4405a

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1025 bytes
namespace:  11 bytes
token:      tokenstring

Comment: your dasboard is in default namespace? can you check by changing `namespace: default` in your yaml file?

Comment: no its not in default namespace

Comment: can you check `$ kubectl proxy --disable-filter=true --address=0.0.0.0` and hitting by localhost ?

Comment: kubectl proxy --disable-filter=true --address=0.0.0.0 Not working

Comment: Thanks for your time @Roman

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

Roman Marusyk is on the right path. This is what you have to do.

```
$ kubectl get secret -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                               TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-rqw2l                kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      9m8s
kubernetes-dashboard-certs         Opaque                                0      9m8s
kubernetes-dashboard-csrf          Opaque                                1      9m8s
kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder    Opaque                                2      9m8s
kubernetes-dashboard-token-5tqvd   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      9m8s
```

From here you will get the `kubernetes-dashboard-token-5tqvd`, which is the secret holding the token to access the dashboard.

```
$ kubectl get secret kubernetes-dashboard-token-5tqvd -n kubernetes-dashboard -oyaml | grep -m 1 token | awk -F : '{print $2}'
 ZXlK...
```

Now you will need to decode it:

```
echo -n ZXlK... | base64 -d
eyJhb...
```

introduce the token in the sign in page:

[image]

And you are in.

**UPDATE**

You can also do the 2 steps in one to get the secret and decode it:

```
$ kubectl get secret kubernetes-dashboard-token-5tqvd -n kubernetes-dashboard -oyaml | grep -m 1 token | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | base64 -d
```

Comment: When we click on sign in it hit multiple rest api's, 1.login, 2.login, 3.config, 4.status......  At 3 api config it returns with that Unauthorized error. I don't know actually whats happening in that service so i can address the issue.

Comment: can you confirm you are installing the dashboard with the following command? `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml`

Comment: Can you run the command again, and confirm all the objects had been installed? what about the logs? can you check if there is anything weird in the logs? `kubectl logs POD_NAME` Also, try on  a different browser, just in case. Finally, have you tried deleting the pod and trying again upon recreation?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a brand new cluster. I simply can't sign in using any token. Even created a super elevated user, same api errors all the time.

Comment: you are on the login page? are you installing the dashboard with the above command? are you getting the right secret? are you decoding the secret without any space or any extra character? If all the answers are yes, then you should ask a question to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

> `namespace: kube-system`

Usually, Kubernetes Dashboard runs in `namespace: kubernetes-dashboard`

Please ensure that you have the correct namespace for `ClusterRoleBinding` and `ServiceAccount`. 
If you have been installing the dashboard according to the official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/), then it was installed to `kubernetes-dashboard` namespace.
You can check this [post](https://knp84.livejournal.com/15984.html) for reference.

EDIT 22-May-2020

> Issue was i'm accessing dashboard UI through http protocal from external machine and use default ClusterIP.

Indeed, the Dashboard should not be exposed publicly over HTTP. For domains accessed over HTTP it will not be possible to sign in. Nothing will happen after clicking 'Sign In' button on login page.

That is discussed in details in this post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907168). There is a workaround for that behavior discussed in a same thread. Basically it is the same thing I've been referring to here: "You can check this post for reference. "

Comment: All things are their as you mention @Nick

Comment: some logs from coredns   E0519 16:18:28.194204       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"

Comment: Am I right that the issue is only with the dashboard and all the other cluster components are working?  All the workleads are accessible, etc?

Comment: Issue has fixed now we can't login by external network using http, we need to edit dashboard service and change type ClusterIP to NodePort and then access url on that port with https.

Comment: So what was the issue?

Comment: Issue was i'm accessing dashboard UI through http protocal from external machine and use default ClusterIP.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/3216
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907168/not-able-to-login-to-kubernetes-dashboard-using-token-with-service-account